# video can't auto load in mobile browser (chrome and safari)

Tags: video.js, preload, autoplay, mobile-browser

I am facing a problem in **videojs** where the video preload in the desktop browser but not on the phone browser, I am facing loading problem in only mobile browser it's cant't preload